# How to I add multiple lines for the subtitle of the map pin in the the map view objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

At the moment I can add one line using this method in my mappoint.m

```
-(id) initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c title:(NSString *)t subtitle:(NSString *) st {
    self.coordinate = c;
    self.title = t;
    self.subtitle = st;
    return  self;
}
```